# Conditional replacement of a character

Tags: pcre

I would like to replace a character in a long string only if a special sequence is present in the input.
Example:

```
This string is a sample! I wrote it to describe my problem! I hope somebody can help me with this! I have the ID: 12345! That's all!
```

My desired output is:

```
This string is a sample. I wrote it to describe my problem. I hope somebody can help me with this. I have the ID: 12345. That's all.
```

Only when '12345' present in the input string.

I tried (positive|negative) look(ahead|behind)

```
(?<!=12345)(!+(.*))+
```

Does not work, so as ?=, ?!...

Is this possible with PCRE replacement in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is possible with any regex flavor supporting `\G` "string start/end of the previous match" operator. You may replace with `$1` + desired text when searching with the following patterns:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*CHECKME))(.*?)REPLACEME     <-- Replace REPLACEME if CHECKME is present
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?!.*CHECKME))(.*?)REPLACEME     <-- Replace REPLACEME if CHECKME is absent
```

With Perl/PCRE/Onigmo that support `\K`, you may replace with your required text when searching with

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*CHECKME)).*?\KREPLACEME     <-- Replace REPLACEME if CHECKME is present
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?!.*CHECKME)).*?\KREPLACEME     <-- Replace REPLACEME if CHECKME is absent
```

In your case, since the text searched for is a *single character*, you may use a more efficient regex with just one `.*`:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*12345))[^!]*\K!
```

and replace with `.` (or with `$1.` if you use `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*12345))([^!]*)!`). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qSC7QP/1).

If there can be line breaks in the string use `(?s)(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*12345))[^!]*\K!`.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*12345))` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the start of a string position followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last occurrence of `12345` (`^(?=.*12345)`)
- `[^!]*` - 0 or more chars other than `!`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far in the match memory buffer
- `!` - a `!` char.

Comment: Meanwhile you edited the answer and it solved my issue 100%. It turned out that the application we are using does not support PCRE but it is Java. So the one without \K works flawlessly. You spared me some hours ;)

Comment: I see, I added both options to the answer.